# Blog Page doesn't show summary but full content

Tags: posts, blog

I am new to Wordpress and I have encountered a troubling issue.
I have 6 posts already present on my posts section and I want them as summary to the blog page. I did make the changes in the Reading settings for the same by selecting **For each article in a feed, show** as **summary** . But I still get a full content on my blog page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "For each article in a feed, show as summary". I think this is about RSS feeds and is related to the length of the article (excerpt or full length). If the loop in your posts section has a hardcoded parameter like `posts_per_page=-1`, then the backend settings won't have any influence.

Comment: Whether an excerpt or the full post is displayed is entirely up to the theme you are using. Have you looked in the theme's settings (possibly in the Dashboard, or in the Customiser for more modern themes)?

Comment: @Michael can you tell me where can I find this posts_per_page part.

Comment: @PeterHvD I will have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `the_excerpt()` function instead of `the_content()`

Hope this will help

Comment: You mean the other way around? :-)

Comment: Absolutely ! you can use excerpt for short description in your loop :)

Comment: can you share the link from which i can use refer this solution?

Comment: Please check **https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/** here

Comment: @PratikPatel I do not have any post-template.php page in my editor.

Comment: If you want to do in specific post using editor then you can add content using  **Insert Read More Tag** which is in top of your editor options.

Comment: this suggestion worked

Comment: Excellent ! So please make this answer is usefull and rate it...